# How to disable axis in all subplots within one figure?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

my friend and I want to plot 32 subplots into one figure. All of them have to have their axes disabled. At the moment we iterate over all subplots, do their calculations and do

```
axis off
```

for each subplot. 33% of our overall time originates from that line. Is there a way to shut off axes for all subplots at once or another faster method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#buk989s-1-visibility), `axis off` just sets the [`'Visible'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7_sep_shared-Visible) property of the current axes to `'off'`. So you can turn off all axes of the current figure at once with

```
set(get(gcf, 'Children'), 'Visible', 'off')
```

However, the above code also removes the axis title, because somehow it also sets the `'Visible'` property of the title `Text` objects to `'off'`. To avoid this, you can use the following, which removes the *x*-axes, the *y*-axes and the background color, without affecting the title:

```
t = get(get(gcf, 'Children'), 'XAxis');
set([t{:}], 'Visible', 'off')
t = get(get(gcf, 'Children'), 'YAxis');
set([t{:}], 'Visible', 'off')
set(get(gcf, 'Children'), 'Color', 'none')
```

Or you could do as in the first approach and then restore the titles:

```
set(get(gcf, 'Children'), 'Visible', 'off')
t = get(get(gcf, 'Children'), 'Title');
set([t{:}], 'Visible', 'on')
```

Comment: That's a lot faster, ty. We need a title for every subplot however. Can this be modified to help with that?

Comment: We assign a title to every subplot and your solution erases it. I didn't specify that enough in my comment.

Comment: @Derdesdoof Your question was clear. I hadn't noticed that `set(get(gcf, 'Children'), 'Visible', 'off')` removes the title whereas àxis of` doesn't. Please see edited answer

Comment: Thanks! That shaved off around 20% of our calculation time.

Comment: Can we assign titles in the same way? The title is partially a string and partially an integer taken from a vector. ```title(['bla',num2str(a)]) ```where "a" represents one entry of the vector.

Comment: Is getting the handle for the title just really slow? Or is there a quick way to get it?

Comment: I added a third method. Give a try in case it's faster. As for how to create the titles in one go, try something like this example: `subplot(211), subplot(212), t = get(get(gcf, 'Children'), 'Title'); title_strings = cellstr(compose("bla %i", [1 2])).'; set([t{:}], {'String'}, title_strings)`

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try that one out tomorrow.